# Как вставить текст в текстовом поле и сохранить в файл?

Tags: php, html

Как вставить текст в текстовом поле и сохранить в файл?

```
<FORM NAME="forml" METHOD="POST" ACTION="#">
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" SAVE "D:\R1\CR1">
    <INPUT NAME="Button" TYPE="HIDDEN">
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="SAVE">
</FORM>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["Button"]))
        echo $_POST["Button"];
?>
```

Comment: Уточните одробности вопроса, какие у вас проблемы, что уже пробовали, с чем столкнулись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У поля `<input>` нет атрибута `SAVE`. Вам нужно задать текстовому полю атрибут `name` и передать значение этого поля на сервер.

```
...
<input type="text" name="textfield">
...

<?php
...
$file = 'PATH'; //путь к файлу
file_put_contents($file, $_POST['textfield']);
?>
```

Файл должен находиться на сервере, как и этот скрипт.
На сервере должен быть установлен PHP.